# Is there a workaround for: FileFilter doesn't work in Windows?

Tags: java, jfilechooser, filefilter

The following JFileChooser code works fine, except that the FileFilter doesn't filter. It doesn't do anything. From another stackoverflow answer: "Filename filters do not function in Sun's reference implementation for Microsoft Windows."
[Comment from Nov 21st, 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713398/filter-not-working-in-filedialog)

Is there a FileFilter workaround for Windows?

```
public String getPathFileName(String startingDir) {
   String returnSelectedFile = "";
   JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(startingDir);
   FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel file", "xls", "xlsx");
   fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
   int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
   if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
       returnSelectedFile = selectedFile.getPath();
   }
   return returnSelectedFile;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this to work:

`final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV FILES", "csv"));`

I have found that this works for one file filter, but I cannot confirm for multiple file filters.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Nick, that works perfectly for what I need. Thanks very much! Sorry I can't give you an up vote because I don't have a high-enough reputation score yet. But it is appreciated.

Comment: You should accept the answer as correct and @Nick will get rep for it..

Comment: Glad to be of assistance @Tommus